# Why I've weak Bluetooth signal with Sim800C and how to strengthen it?

Tags: pcb, noise, antenna, bluetooth, simcom

I've designed a circuit and used SIM800C module to work with its standard Bluetooth and GSM module. GSM works well, but its Bluetooth has weak signal, which I've to stick my phone to the board.

In datasheet there are some concerns about its Antenna:

Antenna Interface:

The length of trace between pin output and connector should be as short as possible;
Do not trace RF signal over across the board;
The RF signal should be far away from SIM card, power ICs.

Is the problem because Sim800C is placed near to the power supply and GSM module and their noise interfere with the Bluetooth antenna? or what could be the problem?

Here is a picture of the board:

[image]

Updated:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you using for an antenna? Just the 2 prongs of that component? Or is there an external antenna that plugs into that?

Comment: @RonBeyer updated and added 2 pictures.

Comment: Tou can’t simply use a bit of wire to connect an antenna - it must be coax.